# Abrir archivo .txt una vez cerrado

Tags: c#

tengo un problema en mi código, y es que necesito volver a abrir un archivo que ya había cerrado para escribir en él. Es decir, yo cierro mi archivo para leer lo que tiene, pero luego no me deja escribir de nuevo en el archivo porque ya lo he cerrado, y no se como volver a abrirlo. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería.

```
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            writer.Close();
            string fichero = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"lista.txt");
                    Console.WriteLine("Contenido del archivo =\n {0}", fichero);
                    Console.ReadKey();

                            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el numero de telefonos que quiere agregar: ");
                            int numeroTelefono = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            for (int i = 0; i < numeroTelefono; i++)
                            {
                                telefono = new Telefono();
                                Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el nombre del teléfono: ");
                                nombreTelefono = Console.ReadLine();
                                telefono.SetNombreDispositivo(nombreTelefono);
                                Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el numero de camaras: ");
                                camarasTelefono = Console.ReadLine();
                                telefono.SetNumeroCamaras(camarasTelefono);
                                Console.WriteLine("Introduzca la marca de su movil: ");
                                apple = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                                dispositivosTienda.Add(telefono);

                                writer.WriteLine("Telefono:\nNombre: " + telefono.GetNombreDispositivo(nombreTelefono) + ". Número de cámaras: " + telefono.GetNumeroCamaras(camarasTelefono) + ". " + telefono.marca(apple));
                            }
```

Comment: Intenta cambiando `FileMode.Create` por `FileMode.Open` la segunda vez.

Comment: Coloca todo el codigo, ahi lo estas queriendo abrir y no grabaste nada y lo cerraste

Comment: using (FileStream fileStream= new FileStream( /* ... */ )) {
 // aqui tu codigo--de esta manera liberas el archivo del stream.
}

Comment: @EmmanuelLG no me deja, ya que me dice que fileStream se está declarando para un ámbito local envolvente

Comment: @RamiroBarone ahí lo he editado, disculpe. La idea es cerrar para que pueda leerlo pero luego quiero volver a abrirlo para poder escribir la información que ponga el usuario sobre el teléfono

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas cerrando el Writer al principio al usar la sentencia

```
writer.close();
```

Debes tener un writer abierto al momento de querer escribir en él y no es posible reutilizarlo, por lo que debes crear otro FileStream y StreamWriter.

Sugiero refactorizar un poco tu código para que no tengas que crear dos diferentes

```
            string fileName = "lista.txt";
            if (File.Exists(fileName)) // Verifica si el archivo existe antes de leerlo
            {
                string fichero = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                Console.WriteLine("Contenido del archivo =\n {0}", fichero);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el numero de telefonos que quiere agregar: ");
            int numeroTelefono = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < numeroTelefono; i++)
            {
                telefono = new Telefono();
                Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el nombre del teléfono: ");
                nombreTelefono = Console.ReadLine();
                telefono.SetNombreDispositivo(nombreTelefono);
                Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el numero de camaras: ");
                camarasTelefono = Console.ReadLine();
                telefono.SetNumeroCamaras(camarasTelefono);
                Console.WriteLine("Introduzca la marca de su movil: ");
                apple = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                dispositivosTienda.Add(telefono);

                writer.WriteLine("Telefono:\nNombre: " + telefono.GetNombreDispositivo(nombreTelefono) + ". Número de cámaras: " + telefono.GetNumeroCamaras(camarasTelefono) + ". " + telefono.marca(apple));
            }

            writer.Close(); // Cierre del Writer
```